# Triying to make an plus calculater

Tags: c

```
    void main ()
{
   int sayi;
   int ikisayi;

printf("first number");

scanf("%d",&sayi);

printf("second number");

scanf ("%d", &ikisayi);

snc = ikisayi + sayi;

printf(\n Total= %f \n , snc );

}
```

What is wrong with that can you help me?

Comment: I finally know what is 'this question does not show any research effort' now. BTW, I didn't downvote you :)

Comment: I'm guessing English is not your first language. Does your compiler give error messages in your first language? Either way, the compiler generally tells you what is wrong; you have to read and understand the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `int snc;`, and the format specifier in `printf` should be `%d`. In addition, the return type of `main` should be `int`, you should include `stdio.h` and you should have double quotes around your format string in `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    printf("first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    c = a + b;
    printf("total: %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, the format string needs to have quotes to be a string: `"Total = %d\n"`.

Comment: Yep, I did mention that in my answer.

Comment: Robert, I have edited my answer with a working code solution.

Comment: Nothing is C-specific in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `printf("\n Total= %d \n" , snc );`